# 16-bit image like SNES

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been trying to make a image look like the images imported onto the SNES. How do you do that kind of image where it looks like it is in the SNES Or maybe in the Sega Genesis, if you don't understand.[image: Look at this image of this guy of Mortal Kombat in SNES.]d. 
Look at the image. You may understand what I want right now. Mortal Kombat in SNES.

Comment: Please show us what you mean. What kind of image do you have? What "look" are you trying to achieve? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you talking about Nintendo? What “images imported onto the SNES” would that be?

Comment: I'm sorry, But look some of the SNES Images, 16-bit images that look cartoony but not pixelated

Comment: I mean SNES Videos on youtubes

Comment: Also, I have tried nothing so far.

Comment: @CyniX425 There are no SNES Videos on YouTube because the SNES was not capable of video. All animation was painstakingly done manually drawing each image pixel by pixel frame by frame.

Comment: @CyniX425 If you want 16bit color video you could look at Sega Genesis which has video playback capabilities. I think you're all turned around in the first place and don't even know what you want. "16-bit images that look cartoony but not pixelated"  Tells me you don't understand the basics of how this hardware works.

Comment: @CyniX425 For authentic SNES style sprite animation you need to follow a simple color palette that's within the SNES color limitations. Do a little more research https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1494/4102/files/pasted_image_0_14_large.png

Comment: @CyniX425 It might have helped your question not get closed if you showed some examples of what you want and what you've tried

Comment: @CyniX425 This is behind the scenes of how they animated the sprites for mortal combat for reference. https://youtu.be/DdzVMD91ofM?t=113

Comment: Yep, I don't understand SNES Hardware. Oh, about the Sega Genesis. In the Sega Genesis Mortal Kombat. How did they put the images inside the Sega Genesis? I want that look and feel of Sega Genesis.

Comment: @CyniX425 You might be a little in over your head. You'll have to study color palettes. And you should probably NOT use the Sega genesis color palette because it's limited to 61 colors on-screen at once. The SNES had 15-bit RGB (32,768 color) palette, with up to 256 simultaneous colors at once. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_game_console_palettes#Mega_Drive/Genesis

Comment: @CyniX425 Also I told you sprites are made by hand. You can't just convert a picture to sprites. You should watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57ibhDU2SAI and http://youtube.com/watch?v=sheOZ-Dlleo

Comment: https://giphy.com/gifs/24cCKnGDPQf9gLmDPY: original doll, add saturation, posterize 8 (remove colors), pixelate, posterize again. Apply palette transformations as you like after